# How to add timestamp to the logfilename with the apache log4j

Tags: apache-2.2

I am new to using apache logger .
I have downloaded the log4j-xx and i have the following text configuration file

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to mainFormat.
log4j.rootLogger = TRACE, mainFormat, FILE


# mainFormat is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.mainFormat=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# mainFormat uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.mainFormat.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mainFormat.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

#File makes a file of the output.
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log4j_HAPR001_OutputFile.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

i use the above config file to create the log file.
Now i wanted to add the current time stamp to the log file.
Is there any way to do this. If yes can some one please give me the instructions how to do.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Swati

Answer (score 1):

The [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) of Log4j does exactly what you want.

Comment: Don't forget to use the correct fileformat to name the file.

Answer (score -1):

Download yourself a copy of org.apache.log4j.FileAppender ([example](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.java.html)).

Copy it into your own namespace and refactor...

Comment out the 'getName' and 'setName' properties and add 'getDirectory' and 'setDirectory' properties.

The clever stuff comes when it makes the *activateOptions()* call and you can now dynamically create the *fileName* variable on the fly.   In your case you'll need to use the *Calendar* class.

Don't forget to change the log4j.properties file, for example:

```
#File makes a file of the output.
#log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE=com.yourcompany.yourFileAppender
#log4j.appender.FILE.File=log4j_HAPR001_OutputFile.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Directory=${catalina.base}/logs
```